# For which $C$ is the linear map $\varphi_C : V \to V, A \mapsto CA$ selfadjoint with scalar product $\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(A^t B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, self-adjoint-operators

Let $V=M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$.

By the definition of selfadjoint, I have to show for which $C$, $\langle \varphi_C(A), B\rangle = \langle A,\varphi_C (B)\rangle$ is true $\forall A,B \in V$. In other words, $\operatorname{tr}((CA)^t B) = \operatorname{tr}(A^t CB)$.

Using some cyclic permutations of trace, I cannot figure out how to do this. Having tried this, it seems to me like this cannot be true since I cannot reform the LHS to have some version of $CB$, instead it amounts to some variant of $BC$ inside the trace. How do I begin? Is this about showing $C$ must be symmetric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given condition implies that $\operatorname{tr}(BA^t(C-C^t))=0$ for all matrices $B$ and $A$. Thus $\operatorname{tr}(X(C-C^t))=0$ for every matrix $X$. Hence $C-C^t$ must be zero, i.e. $C$ must be symmetric.

Comment: Why would this equal zero? What is the given condition?

Comment: @YamahaJacoby $X=BA^t$, If you set $X=(C-C^t)^t$ (e.g. by putting $B=(C-C^t)^t$ and $A=I$), you get $\langle C-C^t,C-C^t\rangle=0$ and hence $C-C^t=0$.

Comment: How do you get $BA^t$? I'm inclined to agree that $C$ is symmetric, but the cyclic permutations inside of the trace don't let me reach some form of $BA^t$ - only $BA^t$.

Comment: Thank you. But what is the given condition in the original post that allows you to follow that $\operatorname{tr}(BA^t(C−C^t))=0$ $\forall A,B\in V$?

Comment: But isn't this using what I'm trying to show, not an initial condition?

Comment: @YamahaJacoby No, it follows from the assumption that $\varphi_C$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise that was a fact that I could use. Is that always the case in questions like this? Ie, if it says "show for which x <something holds>" can I use that <something holds> to find x?

Comment: @YamahaJacoby Yes, by assuming that the desired condition holds, one may narrow down the possible forms of the solutions. However, note that this does not show that the narrowed down possibilities are really the solutions. This is something you need to back-check. In my answer, I only showed that if $\varphi_C$ is self-adjoint, then $C$ must be symmetric. I didn't bother to verify that $\varphi_C$ is really self-adjoint when $C$ is symmetric, because that part is straightforward.